# Jenkins error when calling pipeline B from Pipeline Job A

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am calling a pipeline job (new_job) from pipeline job 'test' along with passing the variables, but it's failing with error.
Both jobs are running fine individually.

Test Job:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Executing First job') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Running first job"'
                }
        }
        stage('Running another job') {
             when {
                     equals expected: true, actual: params.deploy2job
             }
             steps {
                  build job: 'new_job', parameters: [string(name: 'abc', value: qa), string(name: 'xyz', value: test)]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[Pipeline] { (Running another job)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: qa for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:251)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:666)
    at 
....
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates you are trying to refer to a nonexistent variable named `qa` in your Pipline. If this is not a variable declared within the Pipeline, and if you just need to pass the values `qa` and `test` to the `new_job` just wrap the values with quotes.

```
build job: 'new_job', parameters: [string(name: 'abc', value: 'qa'), string(name: 'xyz', value: 'test')]
```